# What is the reason for the warning in the react docs not to use context to pass down props multiple levels?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning about context in order to pass props from a parent component to a deep, deep child component, so that I can avoid passing props to components that don't use them (only their children use them).

I understand I could just get over it and pass props through each component but this feels wrong and I don't want to do it. I don't want to use redux either, because I feel like I shouldn't need it.

So I came across [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context), which seems like the perfect solution if it weren't for this warning:

> Note
>
> Don’t use context just to avoid passing props a few levels down. Stick to cases where the same data needs to be accessed in many components at multiple levels.

What is the reason for this warning?

Comment: Passing props for couple of child components should not feel wrong in the react way.

Comment: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Answer (score 0):

If you have a deep, deep, deep child component, you can use context. This warning is because React Context should be only used as the last option, but you can go with it when you feel like in your case.

Normally, I think in Context like Redux. I ask myself if I need it, if I need more than one minute thinking about it, I surely need it. Good luck!

Comment: You've just restated the warning. What's the reason? What is the downside of using the context API to avoid passing props down a few levels?

Comment: They still have that warning